# Error al compilar en Release: El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'ZXing' no se encontró

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un proyecto **Windows Form** en **Visual Studio C#**, y utiliza la librería **`Zxing`**. Al correr el programa como *debug* funciona perfectamente pero al correrlo como *release* marca el siguiente error:

> Error CS0246
>   El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'ZXing' no se encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de
>   ensamblado?)
>   TScan
>   `D:\Universidad\Residencias Profecionales\Proyecto\Mis_Proyectos\Scaner+Generador\Form_Equipos.cs`

Tengo otras librerías como **`Aforge`** y no tienen ningún problema con ellas.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: agrega las dll del ZXing a la carpeta correspondiente.

Comment: ¿basta con pegar el archivo en la ruta que da el error o se hace de otra forma?

Comment: Tienes que pegarla en la carpeta "NombreProyecto\bin\Release" donde NombreProyecto es la carpeta de tu proyecto

Comment: Si alguna respuesta resolvió el problema puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Elimine la referencia y volví a agregarla, pero parece haberse solucionado con eso.

Comment: ¿Parece o se llegó a solucionar con eso?

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso ese era el error, por encima aparecían warnings avisando que la versión del framework no correspondía -los ignoré por ser warnings-.

Se corrigió cambiando la versión de .NET en las propiedades de la solución.